# How can I change the default error message for a validator in django

Tags: django, validation

I have a model field which uses a validator to restrict the maximum value. However the error message says "Ensure this value is less than or equal to 40.". Is there any way to change this to a custom message?

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
class Bucket(models.Model):
    items = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(40)])
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should subclass `MaxValueValidator` and use it instead:

```
class MyMaxValueValidator(MaxValueValidator):
    message = _('Way over %(limit_value)s.')
```

then

```
class Bucket(models.Model):
    items = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MyMaxValueValidator(40)])
```

*Edit*: If you are using Django >= 1.8 (not released as of this answer) you can skip subclassing and use as @catavaran suggested:

```
class Bucket(models.Model):
    items = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(40, _('Way over %(limit_value)s.')])
```

Comment: @jcasner Could be something to do with the localization not working. Did you try importing `gettext_lazy` instead of `gettext`?

Comment: @Selcuk yes, I am using `from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _`. I've even tried explicitly using `message=_('new message')` just in case (I know, the positional arg should be enough, but it doesn't hurt to use a `kwarg`). Interestingly, if I use `BaseValidator`, I can pass in a message, but as soon as I override `BaseValidator`, I lose that ability.

Comment: @jcasner I suggest you to post this issue as a new question so that more people can see it.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: This feature will be introduced in django 1.8.  For previous versions you should use the subclass as in the @selcuk's answer.

Add the second argument to the `MaxValueValidator` constructor:

```
items = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(40,
                        "The value should be lesser than %(limit_value)s.")])
```